# Enviando Email direto da aplicação

Tags: android

Bom dia, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo na qual preciso pegar um Array de String e enviar por Email direto da aplicação, alguém teria algum noção de como posso fazer isso ?
Obrigado

Comment: Por favor explique melhor o problema, e se possível inclua um [exemplo de código que reproduza o que está acontecendo](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), pois não está percetível a sua pergunta. [Veja na Central de Ajuda Como Perguntar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Olá, posso te passar um exemplo que tenho feito em C#, é só passar como parâmetro o seu array de strings.

```cs
public static void SendEmail(string email, string subject, string[] mensagem, String[] comCopia = null)
        {
            NetworkCredential("email@email.com.br", "password");
            var assunto = subject;
            var emailObj = email;

            var mensagemObj = mensagem;

            string from = new MailAddress("email@email.com", subject).ToString();
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("111.111.111.111")
            {
                UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emai@email.com.br", "password"),
                Port = 587
            };
            //string Server_Name = "http://" + Request.ServerVariables["server_name"] == "localhost" ? Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] : Request.ServerVariables["server_name"] + "/project";

            var html = string.Format("<p>Email: {0}</p>><p>Mensagem: {1}</p>",
                email, mensagem);
            var msg = new MailMessage(from, emailObj, assunto, mensagemObj) { IsBodyHtml = true };
            if (comCopia!=null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < comCopia.Length; i++)
                {
                    msg.CC.Add(comCopia[i]);
                }
            }


            client.Send(msg);

        }
```